# How to stop a user from pressing a button more than once

Tags: vb.net

I've got a small problem of having a button and a combo box. In this situation the combobox holds values from 1 to 10. The enter button allows the user to select how many dynamic objects they want to produce however my program crashes every time I press enter after selecting another value and pressing enter again. So is there any form of validation I can have for my button to stop users from pressing enter twice.

Comment: Disable the button in the click event.  Show us the code that causes the crash.

Comment: Code almost always matters.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Try the My.Computer.ElectrifyChair method.

Comment: You really should look at taking the [tour]. This is your third question and you've yet to respond to anything. We can't help however if we don't see any code. You would think that was obvious when it came to having a problem.

Comment: Sorry this is my first time using this as a forum an overall I am pleased with the help and I appreciate it. However disregard the previous questions before that since I have found solutions to them. Sorry to cause you any inconvenience.

Comment: Thats not how it works. Downvoted questions will count against you forever, even if you delete them (perhaps more so).  You are probably on the verge of being throttled as to how often you can ask questions; if it continues, you can get a ban. The [help] has info on writing a good question, good title etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a flag to supress user events.

Clear it again if need be at the appropriate time.

```
Private Enter_Locked As Boolean
Private Sub btn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn.Click
    If Enter_Locked Then Exit Sub
    Enter_Locked = True
    'do as you will here

End Sub
```